# Stripe javascript not retrieving the token I need to create a charge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to process a payment using a simple stripe charge, the user must pay a quantity in the website through a form and, basically, I don´t know why i am not getting the token back, I think my javascript is not being executed actually. Here is the code:

```
This is the form placed in order#new (the form view)

    :javascript
    Stripe.setPublishableKey("<%= ENV['STRIPE_TEST_PUBLISHABLE_KEY] %>");

.container.body-content
    %h2 
        Complete order: 
        = @cart.name
    %table.table.table-items
        %tr
            %th Design name
            %th Quantity
            %th Price
        - @cart.cart_items.each do |c|
            %tr
                %td= c.design.name
                %td= c.quantity
                %td= c.design.price
        %tr
            %th Total price
            %th
            %th= @total_price
    = simple_form_for(@order, html: { role: "form", class: "cc_form" }) do |f|
        = f.simple_fields_for( :payment ) do |p|
            .row.col-md-12
                .form-group.col-md-4.no-left-padding
                    = p.input :card_number, 
                        label: "Card Number", 
                        label_html: { data: { stripe: "label" } },
                        input_html: { required: "true", data: { stripe: "number" }, class: "form-control" }
                .form-group.col-md-2
                    = p.input :card_cvv, 
                        label: "Card CVV", 
                        label_html: { data: { stripe: 'label' } },
                        input_html: { required: "true", data: { stripe: "cvv" }, class: "form-control" }
                .form-group.col-md-6
                    .col-md-12
                        = p.label :card_expires, "Card expires", data: { stripe: 'label' }
                    .col-md-3
                        = p.select :card_expires_month, options_for_select(Payment.month_options), { include_blank: 'Month' }, data: { stripe: "exp-month" }, class: "form-control", required: true
                    .col-md-3
                        = p.select :card_expires_year, options_for_select(Payment.year_options.push), { include_blank: 'Year' }, data: { stripe: "exp-year" }, class: "form-control", required: true
        = f.hidden_field :cart_id, :value => @cart.id
        = f.hidden_field_tag 'cart', @cart.id
        = f.hidden_field_tag 'total_price', @total_price
        = f.button :submit, "Pay and finish order", class: "btn btn-login"
```

This is orders_controller.rb:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

    include ApplicationHelper

    def index
    end

    def new
        @order = current_user.orders.build
        @cart = Cart.find(params[:format])
        @payment = @order.build_payment
        @total_price = get_total_price_for_navigation_bar
    end

    def create
        @order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)
        @cart = Cart.find(params[:cart])
        @payment = @order.build_payment
        @payment.user_id = current_user.id
        process_payment(params[:total_price])
        if payment.save
            if @order.save
                @cart.purchased = true
                @cart.total_price = params[:total_price]
                @cart.save
                flash[:success] = "Order created"
                redirect_to orders_path
            else
                flash[:danger] = "Order couldn´t be saved, please try again"
                render :new
            end
        else
            flash[:danger] = "There was a problem processing your payment, please try again"
            render :new
        end
    end

    private
        def order_params
            params.require(:order).permit(:cart_id)
        end

        def process_payment(amount)
            #byebug
            token = params[:stripeToken]
            byebug
            # Create a charge: this will charge the user's card
            begin
              charge = Stripe::Charge.create( :amount => amount * 100, :currency => "eur", :source => token, :description => "Example charge")
            rescue Stripe::CardError => e
              # The card has been declined
            end
        end
end
```

and to process the payment I have created credit_card_form.js (of course under assets -> javascripts (I have also removed the turbolinks from application.js )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var show_error, stripeResponseHandler, submitHandler;

    submitHandler = function(event){
        var $form = $(event.target);
        $form.find("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);

        //If stripe was correctly initialized this will create a token using the credit card info
        if(Stripe){
            Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
        } else {
            show_error("Failed to load credit card processing functionality. Please reload this page in your browser.")
        }
        return false;
    };

    $(".cc_form").on('submit', submitHandler);

    stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response){
        var token, $form;

        $form = $('.cc_form');

        if (response.error) {
            console.log(response.error.message);
            show_error(response.error.message);
            $form.find("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            token = response.id;
            $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));
            $form.get(0).submit();
        }
        return false;
    };

    show_error = function(message){
        if($("#flash-messages").size() < 1){
            $('div.container.main div:first').prepend("<div id='flash-messages'></div>")
        }
        $("#flash-messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a><div id="flash_alert">' + message + '</div></div>');
        $('.alert').delay(5000).fadeOut(3000);
        return false;
    };
});
```

When I try to process a payment I never receive the token in the order#create method, so I think that the javascript is not executing

When I inspect variables in terminal I see that the token is not added to the form as a param, as I am suppose to append in stripeResponseHandler in credit_card_form.js this is the output I see when I inspect variables:

```
(byebug) token
nil
(byebug) params
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ps963bnlJwbayybIgXVAu8xQI3L6BneUK6qg5k9U9BV7XL+3M+Bl+OVJqJGNrcMHLAjhjvxOkOlhyig9Sh5Cdw==", "order"=>{"payment_attributes"=>{"card_number"=>"4012888888881881", "card_cvv"=>"123", "card_expires_month"=>"3", "card_expires_year"=>"2017"}, "cart_id"=>"9"}, "cart"=>"9", "total_price"=>"390.0", "controller"=>"orders", "action"=>"create"}
(byebug)
```

Well, I don´t know if I am not seing something stupid or I am completely wrong in my approach, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Antonio

Comment: I think the first step is to add some logging to your `submitHandler`, to ensure that it is actually getting called.

Answer (score 0):

[Update: Problem solved]

After several hours, I found what was the problem, wasn´t the code itself, the problem was HAML actually, precisely the way haml interpretes the form id or the class, I don´t know exactly why but I have changed from haml to .erb file and both the customer creation and the stripe charge are processed correctly. For what i´ve seen, using that haml version of the form stripeResponseHandler wasn´t correctly executed (don´t ask me why, I am not so sure, I just know the form wasn´t updated correctly and the token was not included as a param as I wanted in order to process the charge) that is why the charge wasn´t created successfully.

Hope it helps to someone else.

Regards and thanks to u all.